# Get parent url when iframe is opened php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, url

I'm trying to make a function that redirects to the last page opened after the user is logging in. But it is possible that an iframe is opened and if the user gets redirected when this page is opened i want the user to get redirected to the url of the main page instead of the url of the iframe. I tried using:

```
$url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url = '<script>document.write(window.parent.window.location.pathname);</script>';
```

The first two get the url of the iframe and the third one after i cached the variable start changing when i go to a different page. When i redirect to these url's the first two work but the third one tries to redirect to the full script instead of the result, but if i echo the variable i do get a url. The function is used in laravel and this is the function:

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    $url = "the current url"

    Cache::forget('key');
    Cache::put('key', $url, 10);
    echo '<script>window.parent.window.location.href = \'' . config('app.url') . 'login\'</script>';die();
}
```

This will bring the user to the login page and after the user is logged in it should go to the old page with this function:

```
if(Auth ::attempt(['usr_emailaddress' => $email, 'password' => $pass]))
{
    $value = Cache::get('key');
    return redirect($value);
}
```

Comment: Is the iframe used for logging in? This is a bit confusing.

Comment: The iframe is not the login. the page could be a page for customers and the iframe is all the information for that specific customer.

Comment: In that case I really don't understand the navigation flow here and when the redirect is needed and what the iframe has to do with keeping track of main pages

Comment: You can't directly detect whether or not the request is coming from an iframe, unless you add some parameters in the iframe to identify it. Is that what you were unsure about?

Comment: The user can logout, if the user is on the main page there is no problem because the user will be redirected to the current window, if the user is logged out when he is inside of an iframe the user will be redirected to the iframe window instead of the main window. On loggout the user goes to the redirectTo function where the current url should be saved in the cache. Then the user will get redirected to the login screen. There the user logs in and after that he should be redirected to the cached url. ('http://127.0.0.1:8080/betalingen') instead of (http://127.0.0.1:8080/betalingen/iframe/11).

Comment: The problem is that if the iframe is open the requested url is 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/betalingen/iframe/11', but i want it to be 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/betalingen'

Comment: So the user might click logout inside frame or is it session based? If it is a click just check if current window is the top window

Comment: Its session based, i dont need to check for anything i just need to get the main window url, so: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/betalingen'. right now if there is no iframe open the url is http://127.0.0.1:8080/betalingen but if an iframe is open the requested url becomes http://127.0.0.1:8080/betalingen/iframe/11, this should be the same as the main window, so 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/betalingen'. the code works but the only problem is that i get the wrong url.